# Banno RDC endpoints

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

We're trying to get information from the RDC endpoints but we seem to only be receiving a 500 error. This is the case for all of the RDC endpoints. Below is an example URL;

https://banno.com/a/mobile/api/v0/institutions/xxxxx/users/xxxxxxxxxxxx/rdcAccounts

Below is the documentation I'm following when sending the request:

https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/api-reference/v0/rdc/details/

I can authenticate and hit basically any other endpoints, it's just this RDC endpoint that seems to be giving us trouble. Is there a reason I'm getting a 500 back on these requests, even though I should be getting some data back?

I had sent a message to JHA support on this, and they responded back saying "JHA does not support automation for RDC". So now I'm a little confused - do these RDC endpoints do anything?

Hoping someone here can shed some light.

Thanks!

Comment: We're able to reproduce the same HTTP 500 error and will pass along the reproduction steps to Engineering.

Comment: @JaimeLopezJr. Thank you! Looking forward to your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bzbz the Engineering team has deployed a fix and this should be working.